# std::forward в нешаблонной функции

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть функция, принимающая rvalue ссылку и передающая её другой функции, принимающей rvalue ссылку:

```
void inner(int&& a)
{/* ... */}

void outer(int&& a)
{
    inner(std::move(a));
}
```

Я написал `std::move`, потому что для передачи rvalue ссылок мы вроде как используем `std::move`. Но есть подозрение, что в данном случае будет вызвана лишняя операция перемещения и для её исключения, возможно, стоит вызвать `std::forward`, чтобы передать ссылку напрямую, а не создавать временные объекты и перемещать содержимое между ними:

```
void outer(int&& a)
{
    inner(std::forward(a));
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант правильней?

Comment: Для `int` это вообще не имеет смысла :)

Comment: int использован для примера. На самом деле там сложный класс.

Comment: Да понятно, что вы бы не заморачивались. Еще раз повторюсь - главное, что у вас **всегда** rvalue, это не шаблон, где `T&&` **может** быть rvalue. И поэтому - `std::move()`. Так оно еще и понятнее, что вы хотите сделать - передать в `inner()` именно rvalue. Оставьте шаблоны шаблонам :)

Answer (score 5):

Вообще-то, ни в первом, ни во втором случае сами `move` и `forward` ни к каким действиям не приводят, и никаких лишних перемещений не вызывают.

Как по мне, правильнее и логичнее применение `move` - потому что у вас четко передается rvalue, а не универсальная ссылка, которая может быть и l, и r (в случае шаблонной функции) - и когда нужно просто передать то, что было получено, т.е. lvalue оставить lvalue, а rvalue - rvalue. Это не ваш случай.

*По-моему, так. (с) Пух*

Comment: И то и другое это просто каст. move безусловный, forward  с условием. Поскольку здесь никаких условий нет то и пользоваться forward смысла нет.

Answer (score 5):

`std::forward` требует явного указания шаблонного аргумента и имеет смысл использовать только в контексте шаблонов в универсальными ссылками, которые могут разворачиваться как в rvalue, так и в lvalue. То, что вы написали, а именно `std::forward(a)` просто напросто не скомпилируется.

Т.к. ваши функции принимают rvalue ссылки, то `std::move` тут единственный правильный выбор. С тем же эффектом можно было бы написать `inner(std::forward<S>(a))`, но это длиннее.

Answer (score 4):

Ни `std::move`, ни `std::forward` никогда ничего не перемещают. Они только изменяют квалификаторы ссылочности. Для `int` это вообще не актуально, но если у вас есть класс c конструктором перемещения и копирования, эти квалификаторы ссылочности позволяют выбрать нужный конструктор. Изменение квалификаторов происходит так:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

struct Foo{
  int v = 0;
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(int v_): v{v_} {}
  Foo(const Foo&) = default;
  Foo(Foo&&) = default;
};

void test(){
  Foo f1;

  Foo& ref_foo = f1;
  const Foo& const_ref_foo = ref_foo;
  static_assert(std::is_same< Foo&&      , decltype(std::move(ref_foo))>{}, "");
  static_assert(std::is_same< const Foo&&, decltype(std::move(const_ref_foo))>{}, "");
  static_assert(   std::is_convertible< const Foo&&, const Foo&>{}, ""); // const Foo&& может вызвать конструктор копирования
  static_assert( ! std::is_convertible< const Foo&&, Foo&&>{}, ""); // const Foo&& не может вызвать конструктор перемещения

  static_assert(std::is_same< Foo&&      , decltype(std::forward<Foo>(f1))>{}, ""); // Вызовет конструктор перемещения
  static_assert(std::is_same< Foo&       , decltype(std::forward<Foo&>(ref_foo))>{}, ""); // Вызовет конструктор копирования
  static_assert(std::is_same< const Foo&&, decltype(std::forward<const Foo>(const_ref_foo))>{}, ""); // Вызовет конструктор копирования
}
```

Т.е. в случае

```
void inner(Foo&& a){
}
void outer(Foo&& a){
    inner(std::move(a));
}
```

При вызове `inner` ни копирования, ни перемещения не произойдет, будет просто передана ссылка. А вот при таком использовании:

```
void inner(Foo&& a){
    static Foo v = std::move(a);
}
void outer(Foo&& a){
    inner(std::move(a));
}
```

При вызове `outer` произойдет ровно одно перемещение, причем в теле `inner`, а не `outer`.