# Чем отличаются функции move и forward?

Tags: c++, stl

С функцией `move` вроде бы всё понятно: она приводит любую ссылку на объект к неконстантной rvalue-ссылке, которая в соответствующем контексте передастся либо конструктору перемещения, либо оператору присваивания перемещения. Но я иногда встречаю в коде на C++ вызов функции `forward` в таком же контексте, где я бы использовал `move`. То, что можно нагуглить про эту функцию, понять не получается. Что она делает?

Comment: Предположу, что `forward` более гибкий: он знает не только про право- и левосторонние ссылки, но и значимые (нессылочные) типы.

Comment: Ну, это всё-таки не C#, в C++ нет разделения на ссылочные и значимые типы. По сути rvalue-ссылка - это нечто среднее между просто значением и lvalue-ссылкой.

Comment: Посмотрите [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/714609/stdforward-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8) - там это разбиралось. Без конкретного кода (*"я иногда встречаю в коде на C++ вызов функции forward в таком же контексте, где я бы использовал move"*) вам ответить трудно - я с таким не сталкивался..

Comment: "...вызов функции `forward` в таком же контексте, где я бы использовал `move`". Приведите пример такого контекста, где бы вы "использовали `move`".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция `forward`, как и функция `move`, выполняет приведение аргумента к rvalue. Отличие ее от `move` в том, что приведение она выполняет условное - в зависимости от аргумента результатом `forward` может быть как rvalue, так и lvalue. Используется `forward` в идиоматической конструкции прямой передачи (perfect forwarding), а выглядит эта идиома так:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& arg) {
  . . .
  g(std::forward<T>(arg));
}
```

Суть этой идиомы в том, что **если** ссылка на шаблонизированный тип имеет строго вид `T&&`, и **если** в процессе вывода типа компилятор выполняет свертывание ссылок, то в результате свертывания результирующая ссылка может быть выведена как rvalue, так и lvalue. Использовать `move` в таком случае нельзя, так как программист, вызывающий функцию `f` с обычной переменной в качестве аргумента, может не подозревать, что ее аргумент исчезнет. Тогда как `forward` в таком случае корректно передаст аргумент в `g` как lvalue.

В стандарте такая ссылка называется "передаваемая ссылка" (forwarding reference), но с подачи Скотта Мейерса используется и название "универсальная ссылка" (universal reference).

Шаблон может быть и неявным, например:

```
int j = 0;
auto&& r = j;  // Вывод типа происходит, так что r - передаваемая ссылка.
```

Ситуация с `auto&&` типична для лямбда функций, так что там тоже надо употреблять `move` с осторожностью.

Простой пример работы `forward` и `move`

```
std::string gstr;

template<typename T>
void g(T arg) {
  gstr = std::move(arg);
}

template<typename T>
void f(T&& arg) {
  g(std::move(arg));
}

int main() {
  std::string str { "test" };
  f(str);
```

После выполнения `f(str)` строка "test" перемещается в `gstr`, чего программист, вероятно, не ожидал. Но вот если вызов `g` записать как `g(std::forward<T>(arg))`, то функция `forward` распознает аргумент `arg` как lvalue и строка корректно скопируется.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что в последнем примере forward создаст копию объекта, чтобы его перемещение было уже не страшно?

Comment: Нет, ни `move`, ни `forward` ничего не создают. Эти функции вообще не генерируют кода, это чистые касты. Но если в функции `f` вместо `g(std::move(arg))` написать `g(std::forward<T>(arg))`, то функция `g` будет вызвана с lvalue, и в результате в `g` передастся копия аргумента. Которую `g` затем переместит в `gstr`. Именно при вызове `g` происходит либо перемещение rvalue, либо копирование lvalue.

Comment: Т.е., получается, что forward позволяет вызывать функцию f таким образом, что если я напишу `f(str)`, строка скопируется, а если `f(move(str))`, то переместится? Если вообще убрать `move` в `f`, то строка всегда будет копироваться, а с `move` всегда перемещаться?

Comment: @Modus, совершенно верно, так оно и работает. Аргумент функции `f` имеет специальный вид, и в результате вывода типа может превратиться как в lvalue-ссылку, так и в rvalue-ссылку. Для того, чтобы правильно работать с такими вот не вполне определенными ссылками (передать ее в другую функцию, например), и понадобилась функция `forward`. Это собственно, ее единственное применение.

Answer (score 7):

`forward` нужен для того, чтобы пробрасывать изначальный тип дальше по цепочке. Отсюда его имя и единственное назначение. Вот пример:

```
template<typename... Args>
void secondLevel(Args&& ...args)
{
    ...
}
template<typename... Args>
void firstLevel(Args&& ...args)
{
    secondLevel(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Используя пробравсывающие ссылки, мы получаем «истинный» тип переданного нам выражения, а с помощью `forward` мы сохраняем этот же тип для функции `secondLevel` неизменным.

<sub>В [этой статье](http://scrutator.me/post/2011/08/02/rvalue-refs.aspx) я приводил ещё один пример.</sub>

Comment: Перефразируя, `forward` - это что-то вроде условного `move`. Если в универсальную (пробрасывающую) ссылку пришло rvalue, то он работает как `move`. Если lvalue - ничего не делает.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я бы не стал вообще смешивать эти 2 функции. Они совершенно разные и для разных целей. Попытка их сравнить даёт неправильное впечатление, на мой взгляд.

Comment: В Вашей статье я не понял раздельчик про перегрузку. Никак не могу понять, каких знаний мне не хватает, чтобы с этим разобраться.

Comment: @Modus, тогда напишите вопросы комментариями к статье (если они не большие), либо составьте вопросы для этого сайта и задайте их здесь.